# Problem exporting to gltf

Tags: animation, export, error, gltf

Just exporting a model seems to work, but when I try adding animations, I get this error message. Does anyone know what to do about this? (Providing an image since I can't seem to copy the text.)[image: Error message]

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1485

Comment: From the end of the issue that @scurest linked to above, it sounds like this is a known issue in Blender 2.9xx that is fixed in the alpha builds of Blender 3.0.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it isn't an issue in 2.93.6.